# How do I fix issue relating to 'app introspection not allowed'?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 19.10, usb-installation, rufus

Having a problem whilst installing Ubuntu 19.10 on a Kingston traveler 32gb usb pen drive, setup using Rufus.

Boots perfect but during install I chose an 8gb swap partition 4gb EFI partition and rest is root ext4 partition (is this the recommended partition setup?????)

Then whilst it's 'copying files' I get the errors highlighted in the picture attached... Any suggestions?!

Additionally after the 'copying files' stage which took ages haha, the next stage just doesn't progress from 0%.

tried so many 'workarounds' and searched many buntu forums to no avail. please heeeelp :)

Ubuntu install error picture - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYai9.jpg

Comment: Bug previously reported https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-desktop-portal/+bug/1851807 Instrospection defined in https://askubuntu.com/questions/108174/what-does-introspection-mean-and-how-is-it-related-to-gobject-introspection  Please report its reappearance as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-desktop-portal/+bug/1851807/comments/20 and refer back to that bug 1851807.. Also, please try a 1 GB EFI partition and see if it recurs.

Comment: Hi, I have already had a look through this post although I am new to linux and completely don't understand any of these solutions. was hoping for some more personalized help.

will try 1gb EFI partition. after which I'm probably going to use 19.04.4 LTS and see if the problem persists.

Comment: You can just work on that bug, and hopefully fix it. Apart from magic, this is the only way to fix something like that.

Comment: How is this this so @mikewhatever ? there are many people experiencing this issue.

Comment: Also this is my first experience with linux and the response I'm getting is basically 'you're screwed' or 'report the issue'.

is there nobody who has had this issue and manged to fix it?

Comment: Well, if you didn't want to fix it, why ask "How do I fix issue..."?

Comment: I do want to I just mean that I don't understand the help elsewhere on the internet so came here hoping for more clarification.

Comment: Installing 18.04.4 Worked perfect first time. Thank you all for your time :D